# Simulación de ejecución en paralelo con php

Tags: php, php7, algoritmos, jobs, cronjobs

*Agradezco no me sugieran implementar frameworks o librerias de terceros, eso no es lo que busco, no es el objetivo*

### Explicación / Contexto:

1. En lugar de ir llenando el cronjobs de nuevas líneas de comando de
   ejecución; he diseñado un formulario que me permite guardar en una
   base de datos, las tareas que normalmente se hacen o se ejecutan por
   jobs/cronjobs de linux; Esto facilita al desarrollador la creación
   de cronjobs mediante una interface gráfica web desde la plataforma.
2. Que contempla el formulario:

   - Un perfil de Job: código, Tipo, nombre, estatus, descripción.
   - Secciones de parámetros a evaluar/habilitar:

     - Evaluación de fecha en que debe iniciar la ejecución el job.
     - Evaluación hora exacta durante el día en que se debe ejecutar.
     - Evaluación Dia exacto del mes en que se debe ejecutar.
     - Evaluación Dia exacto de se la semana en que se debe ejecutar.
     - Evaluación cíclica: Cada cuantos dias, horas, minutos debe ejecutarse.
     - Evaluación Tiempo extra para lograr la ejecución (tolerancia de hora no exacta); si hay un fallo del S.O y por algún motivo no se ejecuto el jobs, al levantar nuevamente podrá ejecutarse.
     - Evaluación si este jobs es hijo de otro; solo se ejecutaría si el anterior se cumple correctamente y ha terminado.

Imagen de ejemplo formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. entonces; tengo un cron job o jobtask, configurado para ejecutarse cada 1 minuto, esto es el único que debe hacer .
4. siguiendo el diagrama (Figura #2); este job ejecuta un archivo llamado script.sh. Este lo único que hace es ejecutar un archivo php job.php.
5. job.php tiene la responsabilidad de conectarse a la base de datos y evaluar (cada 30 seg) si es necesario ejecutar uno de los N (Existente) cron jobs almacenados...

Imagen de Ejemplo de flujo (Figura #2):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Problema o Situación:

¿por si me preguntan cómo se ejecutan los jobs de la base de datos? pues aquí hay un problema al ser job.php un archivo php; no me permite ejecutar paralelamente cada jobs; primero tengo que terminar uno de los jobs para continuar con el otro, pensé en implementar CURL y hacer peticiones al mismo servidor... pero no sé si sea el camino correcto... de implementar CURL simplemente tendría que configurarlo para no esperar respuesta del servidor.

### Pregunta a resolver:

***¿Existe alguna forma crea hilos de ejecución independientes en PHP y no esperar una respuesta o que finalicen para continuar con el siguiente?***

### Ejemplo de implementación sin paralelismo:

```php
<?php
class Job1 {
    public function execute(){
        //sleep 5 second
        sleep(5);
        echo 'Job1 finished'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
class Job2 {
    public function execute(){
        //sleep 30 second
        sleep(30);
        echo 'Job2 finished'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
class Job3 {
    public function execute(){
        //sleep 15 second
        sleep(15);
        echo 'Job3 finished'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
class Job4 {
    public function execute(){
        //not sleep
        echo 'Job4 finished'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}


$jobs = ['Job1','Job2','Job3','Job4'];


foreach($jobs as $job){
    (new $job())->execute();
}
```

Salida de corriente (tiempo total de funcionamiento 50 s):

```
Job1 finished
Job2 finished
Job3 finished
Job4 finished
```

Salida esperada con ejecución paralela implementada (tiempo total de ejecución 30 segundos):

```
Job4 finished
Job1 finished
Job3 finished
Job2 finished
```

Comment: ¿El uso de [`workers`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.worker.php) no sería una opción?

Comment: @MauricioContreras si pero no se como implementarlo estoy investigando sobre el tema... y no veo un parámetro similar al de curl que una vez enviado a un worker o thread, elimine la recursividad o la la ejecución continua.

Comment: @MauricioContreras class workers Extiende de  Thread  por lo que se necesita instalar la extensión PECL pthreads que esta deprécate o la que se usa actualmente es Parallel ... sigo investigando al respecto.

Comment: Veré de averiguar por mi lado también. Veo que nadie a respondido aún, siendo que, para mi, este tipo de tareas debería ser algo común, o tal vez me equivoco.

Comment: @MauricioContreras encontraste algo???